# How to fix this error while using pandas profiling in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pandas-profiling

Everytime I use pandas profiling in different data sets, notebook shows me this error.

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid
> indices.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('H:\DATA Sets\cereal.csv')

from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

profile = ProfileReport(df,title='cereal-eda',html={'style' : {'full_width':True}})
```

dataset used - cereal.csv from kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/80-cereals

Comment: df is not defined...

Comment: oh yes typing mistake... but still getting error

Answer (score 6):

Edit: A PR has already been made to fix this. It seems to be an issue using Pandas 1.4.[01] See [this issue](https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/issues/911) on pandas-profiling's github.

I think the error occurs because Numpy deprecated indexing arrays in a manner used by one of pandas-profiling's modules.

If you are getting the same traceback I'm getting where this error occurs in `pandas_profiling.model.pandas.utils_pandas`, you should be able to fix this by changing:

`w_median = data[weights == np.max(weights)][0]`

to

`w_median = data[np.where(weights == np.max(weights))][0]`

In the `weighted_median` function in `$(YOUR_VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_OR_PYTHON_DIR)/lib/python$(PYVERSION)/site-packages/pandas-profiling/model/pandas/utils_pandas.py`

(line 13 for pandas-profiling version 3.1.0)

Comment: This is still an issue and this fixed it for me with:
pandas==1.4.1
pandas-profiling==3.1.0

Comment: pandas==1.4.1 and profiling==3.1.0 did *not* fix for me, but the code hack above *did.*